# Return True if and only if ls contains the string 11

Tags: haskell, ghci

Apologies but i'm a complete beginner at Haskell I'm working on a function in Haskell that returns True if an only if a list of integers returns exactly 11 eg.

```
Main> sequenceones  [1,0,1,1,0] 
True    
Main> sequenceones  [1,0,0,1,0,1]   
False   
Main>
```

this is what I have so far:

```
sequenceones :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
sequenceones ls n = (count ls n) == 1
```

Comment: `sequenceonces = Data.List.isInfixOf [1,1]`

Comment: Could you elaborate? What's the second "Int" parameter you're passing?

Comment: @AlexisKing `sequenceonces = Data.List.isInfixOf  [1,1] [1,0,1,1,0]`